# Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $f_n$ and $f$ are measurable functions such that for each $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(\left\lbrace x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\right\rbrace)<\infty.$$
Prove that $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e.

I can only get it for a subsequence so far.  For if
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(\left\lbrace x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\right\rbrace)<\infty,$$
then the divergence test implies that
$$\mu(\left\lbrace x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon\right\rbrace)\rightarrow 0.$$
Thus $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure.  Thus there exists a subsequence $f_{n_j}$ such that $f_{n_j}\rightarrow f$ a.e.

How can I improve this to get the desired result of $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e.?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: What if we have not encountered this Lemma yet?  Is there a more basic route to take?

Answer (score 1):

The proof is standard:
Let $E=\{x|f_n(x) \;\text{do not converge to }f(x)\}$. Then we can write $E$ as 
\begin{equation}
E=\cup_{n\geq 1}\cap_{K\geq 1}\cup_{k\geq K}\{x||f_k(x)-f(x)|>1/n\}
\end{equation}
So 
\begin{equation}
\mu(E)\leq \Sigma_{n\geq 1}\;\mu(\cap_{K\geq 1}\cup_{k\geq K}\{x||f_k(x)-f(x)|>1/n\})
\end{equation}
By the assumption, for any $n$ and $\epsilon>0$, we can find $K_0$ sufficiently large, such that 
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_{k\geq K_0}\;\mu(\{x||f_k(x)-f(x)|>1/n\})<\epsilon
\end{equation}
thus $\mu(\cap_{K\geq 1}\cup_{k\geq K}\{x||f_k(x)-f(x)|>1/n\})\leq \mu(\cup_{k\geq K_0}\{x||f_k(x)-f(x)|>1/n\})<\epsilon$. This implies that
\begin{equation}
\mu(\cap_{K\geq 1}\cup_{k\geq K}\{x||f_k(x)-f(x)|>1/n\})=0
\end{equation}
So $\mu(E)=0$.